# has_and_belongs_to_many vs has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between the
`has_and_belongs_to_many` and
`has_many through` relationships? When and where to use which one?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

As far as I can remember, `has_and_belongs_to_many` gives you a simple lookup table which references your two models.

For example,

Stories can belong to many categories.
Categories can have many stories.

```
Categories_Stories Table
story_id | category_id
```

`has_many :through` gives you a third model which can be used to store various other pieces of information which don't belong to either of the original models.

For example

Person can subscribe to many magazines.
Magazines can have many subscribers.

Thus, we can have a subscription model in the middle, which gives us a similar table to the  earlier example, but with additional properties.

```
Subscriptions Table
person_id | magazine_id | subscription_type | subscription_length | subscription_date
```

And so on.

Comment: note that the table needs to by named in alphabetical order i.e. categories_stories table as opposed to stories_categories - this is the convention that makes it work.

Comment: why must they be alphabetical @Will?

Comment: @ctilley79 that is the convention used. So when the association is set up it knows what table to look for

Comment: @Will I'm getting the exact same thing.  It will not include the additional attribute in writing to the database.  My question has the create statement that active record is writing to the database.  That might help

Comment: @ctilley79 rails tries to figure out which join table to use, but you can overwrite that with the 'class_name' option

Comment: The punch line here is that you will *always* end up needing to add attributes to your join table, sooner or later. Go ahead and use `has_many through:` from the beginning and save pain later. If it turns out you don't add attributes...you still have lost nothing.

Answer (score 43):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don’t need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you’ll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).
>   You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model.

Comment: I would also add that there are a lot of methods rails inserts to has_and_belongs_to_many and not to has_many :through. All of the methods like assigning a collection of values to the association, doesn't seem to show in the documentation for has_many :through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference

Answer (score 17):

My rule of thumb is, can I get by with a list of checkboxes here? If so, then it's a has-and-belongs-to-many (HABTM) association. If I need the checkbox to capture more about the relationship than simply yes/no it belongs, then use `has_many :through`. HABTM is as simple as using the _ids method with a simple_form collection_check_boxes. `has_many :through` often involves `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Answer (score 7):

From my experience it's always better to use `has_many: through` because you can add timestamps to the table. Many times while debugging some `ActiveRecord` objects that are connected through HABTM, I was missing `created_at`, `updated_at` timestamps to get the clue what actually happened.

So keep in mind that it can help you to debug, investigate an issues with the data relations in the context of the time, because without it you are "blind" when relations were created or updated.

Answer (score 5):

You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the answers clarify that you should use `has_and_belongs_to_many` vs. `has_many through:` if you will not need any extra data or validations on the join table.

**However**, beware of taking this approach. In the early stages of application development, it is nearly **impossible** to know what extra features or validations you may need in the far future of your project's lifecycle. If you decided to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, and want to add one simple datapoint or validation 2 years down the road, migrating this change will be extremely difficult and bug-prone. To be safe, default to `has_many :through`

Comment: Can you explain why this would be dangerous and bug prone? a HABTM is _the same_ as a has_many :through, just without the model. You can very gracefully convert a HABTM into a though.

Comment: Here's a good answer to your question, @grepsedawk : https://www.flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many

Answer (score 0):

The simplest rule of thumb is that you can go with  `has_many :through` relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity.

If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a `has_and_belongs_to_many relationship` (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).

You should use `has_many :through` if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my 2c based on some experience and pondering.

Basically, unless I'm extremely sure I won't need to add extra columns on the join model, I default to using has_many through.

From experience, even when I am "sure" I won't need to add column to the join model, I often discover (days or weeks) later that indeed the join model does require columns. So it would have saved hassle to just go with has many through form the beginning.

The simple reason: it's easy to add columns to that join model, but more difficult to add columns to has and belongs to many.

Answer (score -1):

Rails offers two different ways to declare a **many-to-many** relationship between models. The first way is to use **has_and_belongs_to_many**, which allows you to make the association directly:

The second way to declare a many-to-many relationship is to use **has_many :through.** This makes the association indirectly, through a **join model**:

**You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model**.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to what is a very old (>10 years!) thread.