# ActiveRecord finding record by relations requiring all attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Ok, so I am new to ruby and rails and it will probably show with my question.

I am writing a for fun app and have a particularly strange question in regards to finding records in a HABTM relationship. The underlying database is Postgresql

My models look like the following

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :persons
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :families
end
```

Lets say I have 4 people 'Joe', 'Jane', 'Mary', 'Ben'. They can all belong to multiple families.

```
Family 1 << 'Joe', 'Jane', 'Ben'

Family 2 << 'Jane', 'Ben'

Family 3 << 'Joe', 'Jane', 'Ben', 'Mary'
```

I would like to be able to find families by searching for their names

This is what my query currently looks like

```
Family.joins(:persons).where(persons: {name:['Joe','Jane','Ben']})
```

This works great at finding all records that either have Joe or Jane or Ben (all the families) but not at returning records that only have Joe, Jane, and Ben.

In my example, I am looking to find only Family 1, not the other 2.

How can I make sure that I am only finding records that have all of the names, no more, no less.

Is there a better query to write or should I rethink my database structure?

Answer (score 0):

I would set up models this way:

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :persons
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family
end
```

Then add family_id to families table.

Now you can call `family.first.persons`

Or

```
Family.where(id: 1).first.persons
```

Also if you don't find this method suitable, then I'd recommend using `has_many :through` instead of `has_many_and_belongs_to`

Here's more info:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging and some help on the #rubyonrails irc, I came up with this solution.

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.find_by_person_names(persons = [])
    family = nil
    families = Family.joins(:persons).where(persons: {name:persons})
    families.each do |f|
      if f.persons.names.sort == persons.sort
        family = f
      end
    end
    return family
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think a has_many through relationship is more suited: [has_and_belongs_to_many vs has_many through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780798/has-and-belongs-to-many-vs-has-many-through)

Here's an option that doesn't require filtering the results in ruby:

1. Select all `FamilyPerson` objects that have each of the desired people in it
2. Select all `FamilyPerson` objects that have people other than the desired people
3. Select all `Family` objects with ids in the first query results and not the second - in other words, those Families that have all the necessary people and no more

## Implementation

### app/models/family.rb

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :family_people
  has_many :people, through: :family_people

  def self.all_with_members members
    member_ids = members.collect {|m| m.id }

    # FamilyPersons that have each of the members in it
    enough = FamilyPerson.where(person_id: member_ids).group("family_id").having("count(person_id) >= ?", member_ids.count).collect { |fp| fp.family_id }

    # FamilyPersons that have no additional members
    too_many = FamilyPerson.where("person_id NOT IN(?)", member_ids).group("family_id").having("count(person_id) > 0").collect { |fp| fp.family_id }

    Family.find enough - too_many
  end
end
```

### app/models/person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :family_people
  has_many :families, through: :family_people
end
```

### app/models/family_person.rb

```
class FamilyPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family
  belongs_to :person
end
```

### Excerpt from db/schema.rb

```
create_table "families", force: true do |t|
  t.string "name"
end

create_table "family_people", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "person_id"
  t.integer "family_id"
end

create_table "people", force: true do |t|
  t.string "name"
end
```

## Testing

### spec/models/family_spec.rb

*to test with RSpec*

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Family do
  before :each do
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end

  describe "self.all_with_members" do
    it "returns all families that have each person in it" do
      people = [Person.find_by_name("Joe"), Person.find_by_name("Jane"), Person.find_by_name("Ben")]
      expect(Family.all_with_members(people).to_a).to eq Family.where(name: "Family 1").to_a
    end
  end
end
```

### db/seeds.rb

*Seed data*

```
Family.destroy_all
Person.destroy_all
FamilyPerson.destroy_all

joe = Person.create name: "Joe"
jane = Person.create name: "Jane"
ben = Person.create name: "Ben"
mary = Person.create name: "Mary"

family_one = Family.create name: "Family 1"
family_two = Family.create name: "Family 2"
family_three = Family.create name: "Family 3"

family_one.people << joe
family_one.people << jane
family_one.people << ben
family_one.save!

family_two.people << jane
family_two.people << ben
family_two.people << mary
family_two.save!

family_three.people << joe
family_three.people << jane
family_three.people << ben
family_three.people << mary
family_three.save!
```