# Create join table using migrations or models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

As a Ruby on Rails newbie, I'm going through the Rails Guides and tonight is Active Record Migrations.

After finishing the section on Join Tables (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table), I'm left with the impression that using *create_join_table* is preferred (and simpler) than creating the Join Table via **rails generate model**.

Is this a correct assumption? Are there nuances I should be aware of?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this method

Answer (score 8):

Using the example in the guides of categories and products:

A join table works transparently. You only work with the two existing models (`Category` and `Product`), and the join table exists only to enable the HABTM relationship between them, so you can call `category.products`, or `product.categories`, and things just work.

Generating a model, on the other hand, would only be necessary if you need to work with that association as a distinct *thing* in your application (e.g. if you need to do things with a `Categorization` directly).

Contrast the Rails Guides description of a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association ([read more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)):

> A has_and_belongs_to_many association creates a direct many-to-many
>   connection with another model, with no intervening model. For example,
>   if your application includes assemblies and parts, with each assembly
>   having many parts and each part appearing in many assemblies, you
>   could declare the models this way:
>   [image]

with that of a `has_many :through` association ([read more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)):

> A has_many :through association is often used
>   to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This
>   association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with
>   zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third
>   model. For example, consider a medical practice where patients make
>   appointments to see physicians. The relevant association declarations
>   could look like this:
>   [image]

So, yes, you're correct that `create_join_table` would be simpler than creating a model for the association. You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781049/5614706) for another explanation of the difference between these approaches.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It makes complete sense. MVC is a new concept to me but I think I'm getting it.

Answer (score 2):

As the docs mention...

> Migration method `create_join_table` creates a **`HABTM`** join table

--

When you create a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, you *only* need a join table (no model).

`has_and_belongs_to_many` join tables are different from `has_many :through` as they don't have an `id` ([`primary_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key)); `has_many :through` are meant to represent an interim *model*, so each "record" should have a unique identifier.

Thus, your question about whether it's better to create a join *table* through `rails g model` is false. `has_and_belongs_to_many` has no binding model. If you were using `has_many :through`, you'd be able to use the `rails g model` no problem.