# Rails 4.2 has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

## Problem

I have two models a `client` and a `user`.

A `client` can have many `administrators` and a `user` can be the `administrator` of many `clients`.

I found a [couple](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/) of [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780798/has-and-belongs-to-many-vs-has-many-through) that suggest using `has_many :through` is the better way to model this relationship in my situation versus `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

#### User model

```
class V1::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrators,
    class_name: 'V1::ClientAdministrator'

  has_many :clients,
    through: :administrators
    class_name: 'V1::Clients'
```

#### Client model

```
class V1::Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users,
    class_name: "V1::User"

  has_many :administrators,
    through: :users,
    class_name: "V1::ClientAdministrator"

  validates :administrators,
    length: { minimum: 1}
```

#### ClientAdministrator model

```
class V1::ClientAdministrator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :v1_user
  belongs_to :v1_client
end
```

#### Demo using `rails c`

```
u = V1::User.create!(name: 'test_user')
c = V1::Client.new(name: 'test_client')
c.administrators << u
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: V1::ClientAdministrator(#70347494104080) expected, got V1::User(#70347494299440)
```

Before switching to `has_many :through` I was successfully using `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
class V1::Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :administrators,
   -> { uniq },
   join_table: :v1_client_administrators,
   foreign_key: "v1_client_id",
   association_foreign_key: "v1_user_id",
   class_name: "V1::User"
```

The problem with this approach was I was not able to do any validation on the association such as before_destroy make sure there is still one administrator. Additionally, it's likely that I'll add metadata to that relationship in the future.

---

## The ASK

- How can I get / set the `administrators` of the `client`?
- Is there any way that `client.administrators` would be an array of users instead of forcing me to `client.administrators.each { |admin| admin.user}` to get access to the user? (If I eventually add metadata this probably can't doesn't make sense)
- Is there a way to restrict the use of `client.users` in favor of `client.administrators`?
- Do model concerns help here?
- Is this the right approach for ensuring there is always at least one `administrator`?

Comment: a client can have many adminstrators right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe here is what you're looking for, please namespace appropriately:

```
class User
  has_many :clients_users
  has_many :clients, through: :clients_users
end

class Client
    has_many :clients_users
    has_many :administrators, through: :clients_users, source: :user
    validates :adminstrators, presence: true # I think this should ensure at least one admin
end

class ClientsUser
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :user
end



Client.first.administrators # fetch all adminstrators
Client.first.adminstrators << User.first # add an administrator
```