# Rails unique tags for each User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to add tags to Package model, and each user should has his own tags he has created.

Relations will be like:

```
Package
  has_many :tags
  belongs_to :user

User
  has_many :packages
  has_many :tags

Tag
  has_many :packages
  belongs_to :user
```

What associations should I use?

Should I go with `has_and_belongs_to_many` on **Tag** and **Package** or `has_many_through`?
Or just `has_many` on each model?

Comment: It depend. Do you have user_id saved in Tag? or only package have relation with User ?

Comment: I will have user_id saved in Tag if I use plain has_many :tags on User, and belongs_to :user on Tag

Comment: If your current need is that you want to add tag through Package i.e Package is necessary for a tag then there is no need to save user_id in Tag table. You can utilize user_id in Package and you can use `has_many :tags, through: :packages` in User model.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `Package has_many :tags` and `Tag has_many :packages` at the same time. That's right, either `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many through` should be used instead. The difference between them is how you want to handle the join table.

If its only purpose is to hold connections between `tags` and `packages`, then `has_and_belongs_to_many` can be used.

Otherwise, if you want to keep some additional info in join table (such as tag weight for the package), then it could be a separate model; thus the association should be `has_many through`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780798/has-and-belongs-to-many-vs-has-many-through) answer also.

What about associations with `User` model: since both `Package` and `Tag` belong to `User`, both `packages` and `tags` tables materialize that association in a field `user_id`. So `User has_many :packages` and `User has_many :tags`. There are no other options.